# Manage Rewrite rules with AZ CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I need to associate my rewrite rule set with the routings rules in my Application Gateway in Azure using AZ CLI but I can't with the commands I have used.

I tried some commands but any doesn't work.

I need help. I just need to associate my rewrite rule set with the routings rules in my Application Gateway in Azure. And I must do this action with AZ CLI or with some other mechanism that can be automated.

I tried associate the rewrite rules set to my routing rules with these commands:

```
az network application-gateway rewrite-rule set update `
  --gateway-name <application_gateway> `
  --resource-group <resource_group> `
  --name <rewrite_rule_set> `
  --rule-name <routing_rule>
```

--> ERROR: '--rule-name' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.

```
az network application-gateway rewrite-rule set create `
  --resource-group <resource_group> `
  --gateway-name <application_gateway> `
  --name <rewrite rule> `
  --rule-set-type RequestResponse `
  --rule-set-version 1.0 `
  --rule-sequence 100 `
  --action RewriteValue `
  --value <value> `
  --sequence <sequence> `
  --routing-rule-name <routing_rule>
```

--> But I do not need to create a rewrite rule set. I just need to associate a existing rewrite rule set to my routing rules.

I just need to associate my rewrite rule set to my routing rules in my Application Gateway in Azure. And I must do this action with AZ CLI or with some other mechanism that can be automated.

Please I need some help.

Comment: You can use `az network application-gateway rule update` to update a routing rule. Then you will need to specify the `--rewrite-rule-set` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with *@Thomas*, you can make use of below **CLI command** to associate existing rewrite rule set with the routing rule:

```
az network application-gateway rule update -g <rg_name> --gateway-name <appgateway_name> -n <rule_name> --rewrite-rule-set <rewriteruleset_name>
```

I have one application gateway named `appgw1` with below rules:

[image]

I created one rewrite rule set named `srirewrite` without associating it with any rules like this:

[image]

To **associate** existing rewrite rule set with rules, I ran below CLI command:

```
az network application-gateway rule update -g <rg_name> --gateway-name appgw1 -n rule1 --rewrite-rule-set srirewrite
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, **`rule1`** associated with existing **rewrite rule set** successfully like below:

[image]